# Setting UITextView text in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, text, uitextview

I have an `UITextView` in my prototype cell in a `TableView`. 
My problem is that the value is not set.

In the following code I set a title with a label, and the `medShortText` is my `UITextView`.

```
medLabel.text = medi.name

medShortText.text = medi.shortText
```

When I debug this code, then I can see, that the correct value is passed to `UITextView`. 
However in the table view it appears empty. In debug for `medShortText.text` I only see this: `NSBigMutableString`
I put in an alert that pops up on row selection with the text from `UITextView`, and to my surprise what comes up is the original placeholder text (latin garbage).

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace UITextView with a simple UILabel and everything works fine.